# Crear un class dentro de un object en kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy probando el api de Gesture en android y me encuentro con este error:

```
Classifier 'MyGestureSimple' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
```

al momento de crear el objeto `gDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, GestureCustom.MyGestureListener)`

No encuentro cual es el error de mi codigo. Me gustaria saber si es viable crear clases dentro de un object y luego hacer `GestureCustom.MyGestureListener`

Muchas gracias por sus opiniones.

***ActivityMain.kt***

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var gDetector: GestureDetectorCompat? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        gDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, GestureCustom.MyGestureListener)
        configureModeDarkLight()
    }

}
```

***Este es el object, por fuera de la ActivityMain.kt***

```
object GestureCustom {
    class MyGestureListener: GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{
        override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onShowPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }

    class MyGestureSimple: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            return super.onDown(e)
        }

        override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY)
        }
    }

    class MyGestureDoubleTap : GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
        override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onDoubleTapEvent(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarar una clase dentro de un object no la convierte automáticamente en object. Sigue siendo una clase normal que necesitas instanciar para usarla. Agregando los paréntesis se soluciona el error

```
gDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, GestureCustom.MyGestureListener())
```

Si quieres usar esta sintaxis `GestureCustom.MyGestureListener` entonces declarala como object

```
object GestureCustom {
    object MyGestureListener : GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{...}
    ....
}
```

A diferencia de Java donde esta estructura es común, en Kotlin se considera mala práctica usar objects simplemente para crear jerarquías entre clases ya que no hace mas que producir un overhead innecesario.

Esas clases pueden ser independientes aunque estén en el mismo archivo, como lo dice la [documentación](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#source-file-organization):

> Placing multiple declarations (classes, top-level functions or properties) in the same Kotlin source file is encouraged as long as these declarations are closely related to each other semantically, and the file size remains reasonable (not exceeding a few hundred lines).

Si quieres evitar colisión de nombres puedes usar el nombre del package. Por ejemplo si están en un package llamado "gestures", puedes acceder a ella escribiendo `gestures.MyGestureListener`

Comment: Genial tu respuesta, muy buena. Cuando dices   <<Si quieres usar esta sintaxis GestureCustom.MyGestureListener >> la solucion que propones, se llama expresiones de objeto o clases anonimas?

Comment: El termino más apropiado sería *object declaration* pero supongo que también puedes llamarla clase anónima. Expresiones de objeto no porque en este caso no se usó como expresión. En la [documentación](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) puedes encontrar ejemplos de `object` usado como expresión. Es igual pero sin darle un nombre.